# Total derivative chain rule

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Suppose I had a function $f$ from $\Bbb R^3$ to $\Bbb R$.

Suppose that $f(x,y,z) = g \circ (x+y,z)$ for some $g$.

Why does $Df(x,y,z)(a,b,c) = D(g\circ(x+y,z))(a+b,c)$ i.e. why does $(a,b,c)$ become $(a+b,c)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In details, let $h\colon \Bbb R^3 \to \Bbb R^2$, $h(x,y,z) = (x+y,z)$, so that $f = g \circ h$. Then: $$Df(x,y,z) = Dg(x+y,z) \circ Dh(x,y,z),$$by the chain rule. But: $$Dh(x,y,z)(a,b,c) = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 0 \\0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}a \\ b \\ c\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} a+b \\ c\end{pmatrix},$$and we get: $$Df(x,y,z)(a,b,c)= Dg(x+y,z)(a+b,c),$$as we wanted.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30530/discussion-on-answer-by-ivo-terek-total-derivative-chain-rule).